# 大きじゃない vs 大きくない？

Tags: adjectives

If I understand correctly, only 大きくない can be used?

e.g., 猫は大きくない, not 猫は大きじゃない?

Comment: Have you learned about the difference between _na_-adjectives and _i_-adjectives? 大きい is an _i_-adjective.

Comment: You *can* say 大きい**ん**じゃない.

Answer (score 4):

When the adjective 大きい is negated, it becomes 大きくない.

---

Although the word 大きな also exists, you can't replace the な on the end with copula forms like で or だ:

> 大き**な**猫　　　　　　 'large cat'
>
> ＊大き**だ**　　　　　←　 *ungrammatical*
> ＊大き**で**はない　　←　 *ungrammatical*
> ＊大き**じゃ**ない　　←　 *ungrammatical*

This is different from most *na*-adjectives:

> きれい**な**花　　　　　'pretty flower'
>
> きれい**だ**　　　　←　 *grammatical*
> 　きれい**で**はない　←　 *grammatical*
> 　きれい**じゃ**ない　←　 *grammatical*

So even though it ends in な, we have to be careful not to treat this word as a normal *na*-adjective.

---

This word isn't classified as a 形容動詞 (*na*-adjective) in most monolingual dictionaries.  Instead, it's usually classified as a [連体詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E8%A9%9E) (adnominal word).  This is a class of non-inflecting words that appear before nouns, including words like この and とある.

However, [Daijirin](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_ookina_-010) points out that 連体詞 generally can't function predicatively, while 大きな can:

> 耳の大きな人　　←　耳の大きな is a relative clause in which 大きな predicates on 耳

So it may make more sense to classify it as a special kind of 形容動詞 instead, one with a restricted distribution (or set of forms). Either way, though, it's a bit exceptional, so just keep in mind that this word is special and doesn't fit perfectly into any category.

---

In this answer, the ＊ symbol means 'ungrammatical.'

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you say "it is not big", you say "大きくない" in Japanese. 大きじゃない　is wrong. And you can say "大きくはない".